# Sending registration verification e-mails using Authlogic?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authlogic

Is there any way I can get authlogic to send email to my subscribers after they have registered so that they can confirm their account?

Answer (score 3):

It seems like this [Blogpost](http://www.nathancolgate.com/post/184694426/adding-email-and-user-verification-to-authlogic) describes what you want to achieve.

The user model uses a `perishable_token` which is used for a verification url sent to the user's mail adress upon account creation. When the user clicks the url in the mail it triggers an action that sets the corresponding user model to `verified`

Basically you need to validate `UserSession`s depending on whether the corresponding `User` is already verified.

See:

Comment: Excellent post! It has been very useful!

Answer (score 1):

The link suggested by Lennart is a good starting place. However a quick glance at the code reveals these caveats:

1. `Notifier#deliver_password_reset_instructions` is unimplemented yet is called from `User#deliver_password_reset_instructions!`
2. Notifier is a poorly named class. A Mailer generally sends notifications, so I would recommend naming the mailer class UserMailer to indicate what it is sending mail for. Also as Mailers currently reside in app/models (until Rails 3.0), appending Mailer to the class name makes it clear that it is in fact a mailer class and not an ActiveRecord model.
3. Mailers should not be in the model. They should be in your controller actions. [Ask DHH](http://loudthinking.com/posts/43-think-of-emails-as-views-delivered-through-smtp).

Good luck! Ask if you get stuck.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the Ben Johnson's blog, the author of Authlogic. He has written awesome [Tutorial: Reset passwords with Authlogic the RESTful way](http://www.binarylogic.com/2008/11/16/tutorial-reset-passwords-with-authlogic/). Account confirmation is doing the same way and even less complex.

Answer (score 1):

Is there any reason why you couldn't have an UserObserver (or ActivationObserver if you have multiple authentication models - e.g., admin, user, customer service rep, etc.) that sent an email out once someone is created?

Answer (score 0):

You might find [auth_helpers](http://github.com/dcrec1/auth_helpers) helpful. It's "a collection of modules and controller to extend your Authlogic models. Currently it supports Confirmable and Recoverable behavior."

Comment: be aware that auth_helpers project appears to be abandoned by the original developer and that almost all the links in the readme are broken

Answer (score -1):

Very late to the question but [here](http://brandoncalloway.com/?p=40) is a template with authlogic email verification.